# Recording multi channel / track - SoundCraft Si Compact 24

Tags: recording, multichannel

Can I do multi-channel/track recording on a [SoundCraft Si Compact 24](http://www.soundcraft.com/products/product.aspx?pid=181) with the USB port using the software console?

Would I have to purchase the Si Multi Digital Card for this?

I wanted to record multi-channel and use SoundForge or Cubase or other such software.

Many thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the Si Multi Digital User Guide which should be useful for you:

[Si Multi Digital User Guide Download](http://www.soundcraft.com/downloads/fetchfile.aspx?cat_id=user_guides&id=4585)

> The Soundcraft® Multi Digital card offers digital audio connection
>   between an Si Series  console* and Apple® Mac® enabled with Firewire
>   (1394), or PC enabled with a USB or  Firewire port. Audio capability
>   across the Firewire or USB link is 32 channels in and 32  channels out
>   at 48KHz. In addition to the Firewire/USB ports, the Multi Digital
>   card provides  8 further channels of ADAT in and out at 48KHz. 
>   Connection and setup of the card to a PC is made simple with the use
>   of the Soundcraft  digital audio driver and associated control panel.
>   Firewire connection to a Mac requires  no software or drivers.

This seems to be the cheapest option for connecting to your computer.

Comment: Or in other words: use google before asking ;)

Comment: Where would be the fun in that ;)

Comment: Couldn't have stated it better